# How to inherit styles from parent component?

Tags: angular

In Angular (2+), how can I have a child component inherit styles from a parent component *without modifying the parent component*?

Comment: use global style

Comment: you can point on the same style file in the `styleUrls` array

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you use angular-cli or not. With angular-cli just put the css of the child component in the style `style.css` or `style.scss`. Otherwise the style is encapsulated in the parent component and can not be inherited from the child component. You can use selector `/deep/` in the parent Component or the `::ng-deep` but but that's soon depreciate.
A small trick is to use an input taking as parameter class css. Like this, in the child component:
@`Input() customCss : string = "default-class-css";`